# What is the proper mechanism to pass data via the listener or web service

Tags: java, linux

We have a java listener which picks data from particular devices and process them and finally store them into a database. Now we have a requirement to pass this data to other remote db for some of the devices accordingly. What will be best method to pass it to the remote db is it directly via the java listener or write another daemon to read and send the data? Out platform is linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the code for your current listener than it will be better to add an extra function to it. Maybe add injectable class which will do the extra processing and return to the original listener. This way you will be able to add any number of new functions without changing listener's code later.
If for some reason you will have to follow the second option - separate daemon - than keep in mind possible racing conditions with two daemons accessing the data at the same time and/or in sequence and maybe the data being deleted/changed before one of the daemons had a chance to process it.

Comment: yes you are right i prefer too with the first option as that is more safer.I am using java for the listener how to go about with the injectable class I am not too sure about. The danger of separate daemon on my side I am worried if the first instance is not done yet and the second one is started how to overcome this issue?

Comment: If you are changing/deleting the entry after it is used than most of your concern will be when and how to change/delete it. You will need to post more detailed explanation what you need do, how the processes need to communicate, how the entries need to be processed...

Comment: no most of this entries will be just data capture not change or delete will be involve once it pass through the listener. How it work is basically it will capture the raw data process it and do the storing. So what you think is the best solution here?

Comment: Will you need to flag the entry as processed or delete it from the list/queue (it is not clear how "listener which picks data from particular devices" actually does that). Or did you mean to read the data from the DB as it is written by first listener process? In this case there is no problem, just read committed data.

Comment: the devices will send gps data so we processing their latitude and longitude and store them into the local db. Now we need to make a copy of the data to store into remote db too. Hope is clearer now what the listener does?

Comment: From that I would assume that you want the data from device(s) to be read in real-time and then sent to be stored in DB and (separately) somewhere else. If the number of devices and frequency of polling is high than I would suggest one (or few) fast listener(s) reading the data from devices and producing a number of (2 in your case now) data queues. Than you can have any number of processes (2) consuming the data queues, 1st queue consumer(s) storing data in local DB and 2nd queue consumer(s) sending the data to remote DB. This is probably going to be the most scalable model.

Comment: I have previously used the queue model but is risky because the data must be process before an acknowledgement is sent to the device. So then I move the db pooling mechanism with use of transaction. So why do you suggest to use few listener does your experience say that one is not good enough? So look likes I have to feed one table then another service process that table for remote db is it?